# saving the results of the time command while discarding the results of the command being timed (unix)

Tags: linux, unix, shell, time

I'm timing how long it takes to run a command `foo`. I'm looking to append the results from the `time` command to a file, and discard the results from the `foo` command. I tried the following, but it didn't do what I want:

```
$ time ./foo > /dev/null >> output_from_time_command.txt
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BASH FAQ [entry #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032)

```
{ time ls > /dev/null ; } 2>> output.txt
```